# Interior Points Question

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Solution Attempt

As $A \subseteq A \cup B$ we have $Int(A) \subseteq A \subseteq A \cup B$

Similarly, $Int(B) \subseteq A \cup B$

$\implies Int(A) \cup int(B) \subseteq A \cup B$

Now $Int(A) \cup Int(B)$ is an open subset of $A \cup B$. As $Int(A \cup B)$ is the union of all open subsets of $A \cup B$ we have that $Int(A) \cup Int(B) \subseteq Int(A \cup B)$

Comment: You have proved the other containment, as per your question.

Comment: The title is false in general, as you can see by decomposing an interval into its rational elements and its irrational elements. For the reverse containment, your proof is fine: the union of the two interiors is an open set contained in $A \cup B$ so it is also contained in the interior of $A\cup B$.

Comment: $\text{Int}(A \cup B)  \subset \text{Int}(A) \cup \text{Int}(B)$ is false in general. For example, take $A=[-1,0]$ and $B=[0,1]$.

Comment: I know it's false but still we have to prove it and then provide a counterexample.

Comment: When it's false, how can it be proved?

Comment: @KKA Maybe you misread the prompt, usually the format is "prove <universally quantified statement> *or* provide a counterexample".

Answer (score 2):

The equation is not true in general. Consider the following counterexamples

---

## Counterxample #1

*provided by [Chinnapparaj R](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/378881/chinnapparaj-r)*

Let $A=[-1,0], B=[0,1]$. In this case, $int(A) = (-1,0),\ int(B) = (0,1)$ so that
\begin{align}
int(A)\cup int(B)&= (-1,0)\cup(0,1)
\\&=(-1,1)\setminus\{0\}\\
\end{align}
However, $A\cup B = [-1,1]$ so that $int(A\cup B) = (-1,1)$, which is not a subset of $(-1,1)\setminus \{0\}$.

---

## Counterexample #2

*provided by [Ian](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83396/ian)*

$\newcommand\Q{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$
Consider the subsets $\Q,\ \R\setminus\Q\subset\R$. Now, $int(\Q)=\emptyset$, and $int(\R\setminus\Q)=\emptyset$ so that $int(\Q)\cup int(\R\setminus\Q)=\emptyset$.
However, $\Q\cup(\R\setminus\Q)=\R$, which is not a subset of $\emptyset$.